# Add custom css class to ExtJS 4.0.7 Panel header

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to find a way to add a custom css class to an Ext.panel.Panel using a `title`.

Using a basic Ext panel:

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
    title: 'Test',
    items: []
});
```

The `title` property triggers a header with a series of classes based off of `x-panel-header`. In older versions of Ext, I've read about using both a `header` and `headerCfg` property to customize the panel header properties but they both seem absent from 4.0.7

I also tried building a custom `Ext.panel.Header`, and added it as a `dockedItem`, but it renders with an entirely different set of classes and doesn't behave like the "default" header.

```
dockedItems: [
    new Ext.panel.Header({
        title: 'Test',
        cls: 'emp-panel-header-alt'
        })
    ]
```

It renders with the following classes:

`x-container emp-panel-header-alt x-container-default x-horizontal x-container-horizontal x-container-default-horizontal x-top x-container-top x-container-default-top x-unselectable x-docked x-docked-top x-container-docked-top x-container-default-docked-top`

However, the auto-generated header has the panel header classes:

`x-panel-header x-panel-header-default x-horizontal x-panel-header-horizontal x-panel-header-default-horizontal x-top x-panel-header-top x-panel-header-default-top x-unselectable x-docked x-docked-top x-panel-header-docked-top x-panel-header-default-docked-top`

Also tried adding a class post-instantiation:

`myPanel.header.addClass("some-custom-class") 
// Doesn't work, .header not valid`

`myPanel.getHeader().addClass("some-custom-class") 
// getHeader() valid, but returns undefined`

Comment: So with 4.0+ I suppose you mean 4.0.x ? With 4.1.x and 4.2.x you can use the [header](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-header) config.

Comment: 4.0.7. Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of any easy way to add a class to the header with 4.0.7. You could define your own class which extends from Ext.panel.Panel and has a headerCls config:

```
Ext.define('My.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    headerCls: '',

    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        if (this.headerCls) {
            this.header.addClass(this.headerCls);
        }
    }
});
```

...but that might be a little too much effort for just adding a simple class.

However, couldn't you just add a [cls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-cls) config on the panel itself and address the header with a corresponding CSS selector:

```
.my-class .x-panel-header {}
```

Comment: Adding a class to the panel is my current solution but for now, this class is only for styling changes within the header. I wanted to keep it clean because this will be re-usable throughout an existing project. I guess leaving it at the panel level makes sense if we add more panel style changes for this "alternate" panel design